# Use XGBoost DLL from c# via p/invoke

Tags: c#, .net, dll, pinvoke

I'm trying to use [XGBoost's](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) dll (libxgboost.dll) to create a DMatrix (which is like a 2D array) and get how many columns it has. It runs fine until it throws a `System.AccessViolationException` at the `int cols = ...` line in the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace basicXgboost
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, int silent, IntPtr outputPtr);

    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixNumCol(IntPtr dmatrixPtr, IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IntPtr dmatrixPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000000);
      IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);

      int result = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("../../libs/test.txt", 0, dmatrixPtr);
      int cols = XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, dmatrixColumnsPtr);

      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dmatrixPtr);
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dmatrixColumnsPtr);
    }
  }
}
```

Why does accessing unmanaged memory allocated with `XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, dmatrixColumnsPtr)` cause a `System.AccessViolationException`?

One possibility might be that I'm using pinvoke incorrectly for these functions. Below are the definitions for each dll function I use:

[XGDMatrixCreateFromFile()](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L104)

```
/*!
 * \brief load a data matrix
 * \param fname the name of the file
 * \param silent whether print messages during loading
 * \param out a loaded data matrix
 * \return 0 when success, -1 when failure happens
 */
XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(const char *fname,
                                    int silent,
                                    DMatrixHandle *out);
```

[XGDMatrixNumCol()](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L304)

```
/*!
 * \brief get number of columns
 * \param handle the handle to the DMatrix
 * \param out The output of number of columns
 * \return 0 when success, -1 when failure happens
 */
XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixNumCol(DMatrixHandle handle,
                            bst_ulong *out);
```

[Here](https://github.com/cycloidistic/xgboostDllQuestion) is the repo for my project. I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 . It's built in "Debug" mode (targeting x64) on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit). x64 binaries for libxgboost.dll can be found [here](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/). Although the linked repo does contain a copy of libxgboost.dll.

Comment: Don't make us hunt through off site code. And even then how are we to know what the requirements are for each function? Do you have example C++ code that works.

Comment: Sorry about the wording. I didn't want to make the question too long by copy-pasting all the c++ definitions. Could you clarify what you mean by example C++ code? I'm writing this in C# and everything up to the "int cols = ..." line seems to be working.

Comment: The question has none of the details that matters.

Comment: What details do you recommend I should add then? I'm still trying to get the hang of asking good questions and any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: We don't know what the interface is. Perhaps your pinvokes are wrong. And we don't know how to call it. Example C++ code would help.

Comment: The only relevant C++ code I can find is from the project itself. From lines 104-106 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/6b5a23ccd53960686e6084bcd722bec157883b98/src/c_api/c_api.cc) the interface for XGDMatrixCreateFromFile() is `XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(const char *fname, int silent, DMatrixHandle *out);` and from lines 304-305 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/6b5a23ccd53960686e6084bcd722bec157883b98/src/c_api/c_api.cc), the interface for XGDMatrixNumCol() is 
`XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixNumCol(DMatrixHandle handle, bst_ulong *out);`

Comment: I can only find an example of XGDMatrixCreateFromFile() at line 186 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/445029bb82ff5c52383b741a161a0c03b745529e/jvm-packages/xgboost4j/src/native/xgboost4j.cpp)
and an example of XGDMatrixNumCol() at line 205 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/37bc122c90b7c1337403f797fb7b01fc6abd5b36/R-package/src/xgboost_R.cc).

Comment: Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Never mind. I'm not going to hunt around off site. Good luck.

Comment: I can edit the question to have all the relevant code so you don't have to go off the site.

Comment: Ok I've just added the interface code from the source code itself.

Comment: I've also added the only correct examples I can find for the the usage of each function

Comment: If there's anything else that you'd like me to add I be more than happy to do it :)

Comment: Just did a complete rewrite of the question @DavidHeffernan and NineBerry gave me the right answer. Thank you David for help in rephrasing the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the calling convention Cdecl which seems to be used by the DLL.

Also, the signature of the `XGDMatrixCreateFromFile` function is wrong. The parameter expected is not a pointer to some memory allocated by you, but the function will allocate memory itself and then return the pointer as an output parameter.

Try the following code. Note the use of the the `out` keyword on the `outputPtr` parameter in the `XGDMatrixCreateFromFile` function.

```
[DllImport("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\build\\Release\\libxgboost.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, int silent, out IntPtr outputPtr);

[DllImport("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\build\\Release\\libxgboost.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int XGDMatrixNumCol(IntPtr dmatrixPtr, IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr dmatrixPtr;
    IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);

    int result = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\demo\\data\\agaricus.txt.test", 0, out dmatrixPtr);
    int cols = XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, dmatrixColumnsPtr);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dmatrixColumnsPtr);
}
```

---

When this works, you can then also simplify the call to get the number of columns by using the `ulong` datatype:

```
[DllImport("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\build\\Release\\libxgboost.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, int silent, out IntPtr outputPtr);

[DllImport("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\build\\Release\\libxgboost.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int XGDMatrixNumCol(IntPtr dmatrixPtr, out ulong dmatrixColumnsPtr);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr dmatrixPtr;
    ulong dmatrixColumns;

    int result = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("C:\\dev\\libs\\xgboost\\demo\\data\\agaricus.txt.test", 0, out dmatrixPtr);
    int cols = XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, out dmatrixColumns);
}
```

Comment: Just tried it out and I'm getting the same error :( Although, could you put that answer up on my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580825/why-does-accessing-unmanaged-memory-cause-a-system-accessviolationexception) in which I've rewritten the question in a hopefully better way?

Comment: I'll definitely do that in the future. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Adding the `out` keyword and changing the declarations fixed it for me. Thank you @NineBerry :) Out of curiosity, why does adding `out` fix this?

Comment: Using the out keyword within in the p/invoke context means that runtime does not pass the value of the variable to the function, but a pointer to the variable, so that the function can change the value of the variable.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again for saving me a lot of time :)