# Why does accessing unmanaged memory cause a System.AccessViolationException?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I'm trying to use [XGBoost's](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) dll (libxgboost.dll) to create a DMatrix (which is like a 2D array) and get how many columns it has. It runs fine until it throws a `System.AccessViolationException` at the `int cols = ...` line in the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace basicXgboost
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, int silent, IntPtr outputPtr);

    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixNumCol(IntPtr dmatrixPtr, IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IntPtr dmatrixPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000000);
      IntPtr dmatrixColumnsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);

      int result = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("../../libs/test.txt", 0, dmatrixPtr);
      int cols = XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, dmatrixColumnsPtr);

      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dmatrixPtr);
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dmatrixColumnsPtr);
    }
  }
}
```

Why does accessing unmanaged memory allocated with `XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, dmatrixColumnsPtr)` cause a `System.AccessViolationException`?

One possibility might be that I'm using pinvoke incorrectly for these functions. Below are the definitions for each dll function I use:

[XGDMatrixCreateFromFile()](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L104)

```
/*!
 * \brief load a data matrix
 * \param fname the name of the file
 * \param silent whether print messages during loading
 * \param out a loaded data matrix
 * \return 0 when success, -1 when failure happens
 */
XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(const char *fname,
                                    int silent,
                                    DMatrixHandle *out);
```

[XGDMatrixNumCol()](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L304)

```
/*!
 * \brief get number of columns
 * \param handle the handle to the DMatrix
 * \param out The output of number of columns
 * \return 0 when success, -1 when failure happens
 */
XGB_DLL int XGDMatrixNumCol(DMatrixHandle handle,
                            bst_ulong *out);
```

[Here](https://github.com/cycloidistic/xgboostDllQuestion) is the repo for my project. I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 . It's built in "Debug" mode (targeting x64) on Windows 10 Pro (64-bit). x64 binaries for libxgboost.dll can be found [here](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/). Although the linked repo does contain a copy of libxgboost.dll.

Comment: Does `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(10);` allocate 10 bytes or 10 ints?  And how sure are you that there are only 10 columns?

Comment: I think it allocates 10 bytes if I'm reading the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17(v=vs.110).aspx) right. 10 was just an arbitrary number of bytes which I use to store an integer in memory (which can refer to many more than just 10 columns).

Comment: If XGDMatrixNumCol fills a bst_ulong parameter then you need to know how big a bst_ulong is - is it more or less than 10 bytes?

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thanks NineBerry. I'll do that in the future :) I did it again since I got a lot of good feedback on how to reformat the question so that it's easier for people to look at it.

Comment: Jerry Jeremiah I think it's less than 10 bytes according to its definition [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/b94fcab4dc90cfd6c0a80ac6dc3ea0ad154543a6/include/xgboost/c_api.h#L27)

Comment: Yes, I finally found the source code.  My apologies for the noise - I saw a magic number and instantly expected the worst.

Comment: I think I found the solution with the help of NineBerry. I'll just post it up here in a moment @JerryJeremiah

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution I've got thanks to [NineBerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540784/accessviolationexception-when-accessing-allocated-memory).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace basicXgboost
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixCreateFromFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, int silent, out IntPtr outputPtr);

    [DllImport("../../libs/libxgboost.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int XGDMatrixNumCol(IntPtr dmatrixPtr, out ulong dmatrixColumnsPtr);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      IntPtr dmatrixPtr;
      ulong dmatrixColumns;

      int result = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("../../libs/test.txt", 0, out dmatrixPtr);
      int cols = XGDMatrixNumCol(dmatrixPtr, out dmatrixColumns);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check return values. They're there for a reason. XGDMatrixCreateFromFile could fail.